# How to assign a dynamic imagebrush resource to a stackpanel's background in code?

Tags: wpf, xaml, imagebrush

I currently define the background for a user control like this:

```
<UserControl.Background>
    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{DynamicResource LeftMenuBackgroundImage}" />
</UserControl.Background>
```

How can I move this to code-behind, e.g.:

*PSEUDO-CODE:*

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Background = new ImageBrush(DynamicResource.GetResourceName("LeftMenuBackgroundImage"));
```

Answer (score 2):

allow me to answer this one, got it to work like this:

in code:

```
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.SetResourceReference(StackPanel.BackgroundProperty, "LeftMenuBackgroundImageBrush");
```

in resources:

```
<ImageBrush x:Key="LeftMenuBackgroundImageBrush" 
    ImageSource="{DynamicResource LeftMenuBackgroundImage}"/>

<ImageSource x:Key="LeftMenuBackgroundImage">Images/LeftMenuBackground.jpg</ImageSource>
```